# java binary count

Tags: java, binary

I need to know how to figure out the result of the SOUT without using of PC.

```
public static int bits(int n) {
    return n & (0xeeeeeeee|0x66666666);
}
```

What does it return for `bits(6);`? I know it returns 6, but why?

Comment: Sounds like homework. Work out what the bit patterns for the two values look like, OR them together and see what the result looks like. Then you should be able to work out what happens when you AND with various values for `n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 (0xeeeeeeee)
OR   0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 (0x66666666)
     ---------------------------------------
     1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110
     ---------------------------------------

     1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110 1110
AND                                     0110 (6)
     ---------------------------------------
                                         110 (6)
     ---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 8):

Convert the hexadecimal literals to binary literals by hand and then it will become more clear.

As this is homework, I think that this is an appropriate enough answer without giving too many details away.